# A function that finds the largest number at an index in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, methods

I am doing an online python course and I'm stuck on one of the tasks.

I have a list of lists like below with a string and an int, the int is representative of a weight, and I have a certain weight limit of 10:

```
WeightLimit = 10
MyList = [['ItemOne','9'],['ItemTwo','4'],['ItemThree','7'],['ItemFour','2'], ,['ItemFive','1']]
```

I need to move these items to a new list based on my weight limit, and each new item is essentially a delivery. I need to deliver the heaviest items first.

So essentially ItemOne would be my first and only delivery as my limit is now at 1 (10 - 9). My limit now resets to 10 as I can't deliver anymore. My next delivery would be ItemThree, ItemFour, ItemFive (7 + 2 + 1 = 10). My limit resets to 10 as I can't deliver anymore. My final delivery is now ItemTwo.

My output would be:

```
newList = [['ItemOne'],['ItemThree', 'ItemFour', 'ItemFive'], ['ItemTwo']]
```

So far I have:

```
heaviest = 0
lightest = 10
name = ''
weightLimit = limit
outputList = []
loopList = []

for item in MyList:
    if int(item[1]) > heaviest:
        heaviest = int(item[1])
        name = item[0]
    elif int(item[1]) < lightest:
        lightest = int(item[1])

loopList.append(name)
weightLimit = weightLimit - heaviest

for item in myList:
    if name == item[0]:
        MyList.remove(item)

if lightest > weightLimit:
    weightLimit = 10
    outputList.append(loopList)
    loopList = []
```

So that basically goes through and finds the heaviest item, and the lightest item. If the lightest item is larger than my remaining limit, everything resets, and the item(s) are added to the output list.

Comment: You clearly have already solved the puzzle in your head, so you just have to go back over that algorithm and translate it into code. It would be bad form to help you solve an online course exercise, but a few pointers:
- you can expect to be walking over the list of items multiple times in the same order

- you need to keep track of a few states (which items are still to be delivered, how much "space" is remaining, etc)
- then, depending on the exercise, you can e.g. put chunks in smaller functions

Comment: from operator import itemgetter    sorted(MyList, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
output :: [['ItemOne', '9'], ['ItemThree', '7'], ['ItemTwo', '4'], ['ItemFour', '2'], ['ItemFive', '1']]

Comment: You don’t have a string and an `int`: they’re all strings.  Is that how the problem is posed?

Comment: why cant you deliver `itemOne` with `itemFive` 9 + 1 == 10